# Python: How do I get python to open files out of it's folder?

Tags: python

I made a program to open files windows can't but I have to put the file everywhere I want to use it. How can I just give it a path to use to find the file to read?

Basically how would I open a file out of a program's folder?
I would think that it would be...
 `file = open('C://Users/Name/Python33/file','r')` But that isn't working.
Could someone give me example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command line arguments:

sys.argv[...]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either through command line arguments, as suggested by @qarma, or any other kind of I/O (taking `raw_input`, for instance). If you're unfamiliar with accessing files by paths in Python, you may find [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) useful.